# Asymptotic distribution of OLS estimator in a linear regression

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, asymptotics, least-squares, parameter-estimation

I know the standard way of finding the asymptotic distribution of the OLS estimator in a linear regression. Suppose

$$ y_i = x_i'\beta + u_i$$ 
where $u_i |X = x_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Let $\hat{\beta}$ denote the OLS estimator of $\beta$. I know that

$$ \sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta} - \beta) \overset{d}\to N(0,\sigma^2 Q^{-1})$$
where $Q$ is the probability limit of $X'X$, as shown in page 17 of [this document](https://www.bauer.uh.edu/rsusmel/phd/ec1-7.pdf).

However, what's wrong with my attempt to derive the asymptotic distribution?

The CLT tells me

$$\sqrt{n} (\hat{\beta} - \beta) \overset{d}\to N(0, \mathrm{var}(\hat{\beta}))$$

Then define $U = [u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n]'$.

\begin{align}
\mathrm{var}(\hat{\beta}) &= E[(\hat{\beta} - \beta)^2 ] \\
&= E[( (X'X)^{-1}(X'U)) ( (X'X)^{-1}(X'U))'] \\
&= E[( (X'X)^{-1}(X'U)(U'X)(X'X)^{-1}] \\
&= E\bigg[(X'X)^{-1}\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i x_i' u_i^2 \big)(X'X)^{-1} \bigg] \\
&= E\bigg[(X'X)^{-1}\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i x_i' E[u_i^2|X] \big)(X'X)^{-1} \bigg] \\
&= E\bigg[(X'X)^{-1}\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i x_i'\big)(X'X)^{-1} \bigg]\sigma^2 \\
&= E\bigg[(X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)^{-1} \bigg]\sigma^2 \\
&= E[(X'X)^{-1}] \sigma^2
\end{align}

Obviously $E[(X'X)^{-1}] \neq Q^{-1}$, by Jensen's inequality. What went wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that $u_i\mid X_i=x\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because 
$$
\sqrt{n} (\hat{\beta}_n - \beta) \overset{d}{\not\to} N(0, \operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta}_n)).
$$
Instead,
$$
\sqrt{n} (\hat{\beta}_n - \beta)\xrightarrow{d}N(0,\Sigma),
$$
where
$$
\Sigma=Q^{-1}\operatorname{Var}(x_1u_1)Q^{-1}=\sigma^2Q^{-1}QQ^{-1}=\sigma^2Q^{-1}
$$
and $Q=\operatorname{plim}n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^{\top}$.

Comment: So I applied the CLT incorrectly? Because $\hat{\beta}$ is not a sample mean?

Comment: It is 
$$
\hat{\beta}_n=\beta+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^{\top}\right)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n x_iu_i.
$$
So it is $\beta$ plus the sample mean of $\{x_1u_1,\ldots,x_nu_n\}$ scaled by $=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^{\top}\right)^{-1}$.